# WPF Отображение данных из Com-порта

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть устройство (весы), которое на Com-порт кидает со скоростью 10 раз в секунду значение (текстовая строчка). Мне нужно написать приложение позволяющее слушать Com-порт и выводить эту строчку на экран.
При запуске, программа должна сразу  читать данные из порта. Вроде ничего сложного. Вывожу значение в простой Label. Если запускаю приложение, то всё ок, если мне требуется остановить порт, а затем запустить, то столкнулся с тем, что Label не успевает отрисовывать, либо наоборот слишком быстро идет обновление. Сделал таким образом:

```
public void Service_Start()
{
    try
    {
        serial.PortName = "COM1";
        serial.BaudRate = 9600;
        serial.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
        serial.Parity = Parity.None;
        serial.DataBits = 8;
        serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serial.ReadTimeout = 200;                
        serial.Open();
        serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recieve);    
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Не удается найти Com Port. Пожалуйста проверьте настройки подключения");
    }
}    

private delegate void UpTDelegate(string text);

private void Recieve(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{            
    recieved_data = serial.ReadExisting();     
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpTDelegate(WriteData), recieved_data);
}

private void WriteData(string text)
{
    lbl_receive.Content = "Вес: " + text;
}
```

`lbl_receive` - это как раз `Label` в который нужно выводить инфу постоянно

Можете подсказать?

Comment: Можете код отформатировать?

Comment: Может стоит вот этим `serial.ReadTimeout = 200;` параметром поиграться? Это же как раз задержка чтения. Да, и если вы находу отключаете/включаете порт, то вы не забыли ловить эти моменты, чтоб вовремя  отписываться/подписываться от/на `DataReceived`?

Comment: c readtimeout игрался, не помогло. Но вы оказались правы...я забыл отписаться от события при отключении порта. Спасибо,большое